# Disabling weak cypher suites in apache

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I want to disable the following weak cypher suites in my apache server:

[List of ciphers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00ZRF.png)

This thread explains how to do it:
[Disable TLS cipher suites](https://serverfault.com/questions/1056696/disable-tls-cipher-suites)

However, my ssllabs report shows that many weak cyphers are still supported. I tried to disabled them by example using :!weak:!medium:![weak_algo_name] without success.

This is my current relevant ssl.conf:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -SSLv2 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1

SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

SSLHonorCipherOrder     off
```

How can I remove these cypher suites?

Edit:
As Steffen Ullrich mentionned,another config file was taking precedence over the ssl.conf file. After updating that file, it worked properly.

Comment: The part of the configuration you show looks good, but ... Are you sure you are even testing your own server and not some reverse proxy or CDN in front of it? Did you restart the server after reconfiguration? Are there any configurations options in this or other files which might take precedence over what you've configured?

Comment: I did restart the server after making the changes with `httpd -k restart`. I succesffully disabled tls1.0 and tls1.1 by editing this config file, so it hints me that I am testing the right server. I will look for other files that might take precedence as you mentioned.